# Android FFmpeg sometimes works and sometimes crashes

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I compiled FFmpeg for Android ( https://gitorious.org/android-ffmpeg ) but when I'm trying to do some operations ( f.e filters cropping, transpose, trim etc ) it crashes in 5 on 10 cases.
Error logs are not the same so I assume that it might be caused by memory issues.
I'm using OSX, NDK android-ndk-r9b : darwing x86_64.
Native ffmpeg method is passing args to ffmpeg.c main method. It's executed in AsyncTask in Activity.
Thanks in advance

*EDIT:
I forgot to mention that programs algorithm runs like that:
Press Button - > Open Camera Intent - > Start recording - > After recording copy file to project folder ( on SD card ) - > Open edit activity + Start asynctask*

*EDIT2: 
Tested on HTC ONE with different video resolutions*

Version and config of ffmpeg

```
11-20 12:15:23.001: I/ff-log(19091): ffmpeg version 0.10.2.git
11-20 12:15:23.001: I/ff-log(19091):  Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
11-20 12:15:23.001: I/ff-log(19091):   built on Nov 20 2013 12:12:46 with gcc 4.6 20120106 (prerelease)
11-20 12:15:23.001: I/ff-log(19091):   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=armv7-a --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-network --disable-avdevice --enable-protocol=file --enable-hwaccel=mpeg4_vaapi --enable-hwaccel=h264_vaapi --sysroot=/Users/dpc/Developer/android-ndk-r9b/platforms/android-9/arch-arm --disable-decoder=h264_vdpau --prefix=build/armv7-a --disable-asm --enable-small --disable-everything --enable-decoder=mjpeg --enable-parser=mjpeg --enable-muxer=mp4 --enable-muxer=h264 --enable-muxer=h263 --enable-muxer=yuv4mpegpipe --enable-muxer=mov --enable-demuxer=mpegvideo --enable-demuxer=mjpeg --enable-demuxer=image2 --enable-demuxer=mp4 --enable-demuxer=aac --enable-demuxer=ac3 --enable-demuxer=mp3 --enable-demuxer=yuv4mpegpipe --enable-demuxer=mov --enable-decoder=mpegvideo --enable-decoder=mpeg4 --enable-decoder=mp3 --enable-decoder=ac3 --enable-decoder=aac --enable-decoder=h264 --enable-decoder=h263 --enable-decoder=rawvideo --enable-decoder=yuv4 --enable-decoder=png --enable
```

Sample comand:

```
1-20 12:15:22.991: I/FFMPEG(19091): CMD:-i file:/storage/emulated/0/.project/videos/mac_video_tmp.mp4 -vf crop=1079:1079:0:420 -vcodec mpeg4 -sameq -acodec copy file:/storage/emulated/0/.project/videos/croppedVid.mp4
```

Some output errors:

1st type:

```
   11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091):   libavutil      51. 46.100 / 51. 46.100
11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091):   libavcodec     54. 14.101 / 54. 14.101
11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091):   libavformat    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091):   libavfilter     2. 70.100 /  2. 70.100
11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091):   libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091):   libswresample   0. 11.100 /  0. 11.100
11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091): before parsing options
11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091): before parsing options
11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091): parse options
11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091): prepare app arguments !!! NOT defined(_WIN32) && !defined(__MINGW32CE__) !
11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091): after prepare app arguments
11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091): ffurl_open: file:/storage/emulated/0/.project/videos/mac_video_tmp.mp4, 1
11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091): ffurl_alloc: file:/storage/emulated/0/.project/videos/mac_video_tmp.mp4, 1
11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091): ffurl_alloc: file
11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091): ffurl_open alloc: 0
11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091): ffurl_connect
11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091): ffurl_open connect: 0
11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091): Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
11-20 12:15:23.011: I/ff-log(19091): ISO: File Type Major Brand: isom
11-20 12:15:23.021: I/ff-log(19091): File position before avformat_find_stream_info() is 8458240
11-20 12:15:23.041: A/libc(19091): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 19091 (t.android.utils)
```

Second type:

```
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632):   libavutil      51. 46.100 / 51. 46.100
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632):   libavcodec     54. 14.101 / 54. 14.101
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632):   libavformat    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632):   libavfilter     2. 70.100 /  2. 70.100
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632):   libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632):   libswresample   0. 11.100 /  0. 11.100
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632): before parsing options
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632): before parsing options
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632): parse options
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632): prepare app arguments !!! NOT defined(_WIN32) && !defined(__MINGW32CE__) !
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632): after prepare app arguments
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632): opt_output_file ܞ�f��f��f��f���flated/0/.project/videos/mac_video_tmp.mp4
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632): ffurl_alloc: ܞ�f��f��f��f���flated/0/.project/videos/mac_video_tmp.mp4, 0
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632): ffurl_alloc: file
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632): ffurl_open: ܞ�f��f��f��f���flated/0/.project/videos/mac_video_tmp.mp4, 2
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632): ffurl_alloc: ܞ�f��f��f��f���flated/0/.project/videos/mac_video_tmp.mp4, 2
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632): ffurl_alloc: file
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632): ffurl_open alloc: 0
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632): ffurl_connect
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632): ffurl_open connect: -2
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632): ffurl_open FAIL
11-20 12:17:04.800: I/ff-log(19632): ܞ�f��f��f��f���flated/0/.project/videos/mac_video_tmp.mp4: No such file or directory
```

( CHARSER IS AS IT'S IN OUTPUT LOGCAT )

3rd type:

```
11-20 12:18:23.243: I/ff-log(19867):   libavutil      51. 46.100 / 51. 46.100
11-20 12:18:23.243: I/ff-log(19867):   libavcodec     54. 14.101 / 54. 14.101
11-20 12:18:23.243: I/ff-log(19867):   libavformat    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
11-20 12:18:23.243: I/ff-log(19867):   libavfilter     2. 70.100 /  2. 70.100
11-20 12:18:23.243: I/ff-log(19867):   libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
11-20 12:18:23.243: I/ff-log(19867):   libswresample   0. 11.100 /  0. 11.100
11-20 12:18:23.243: I/ff-log(19867): before parsing options
11-20 12:18:23.243: I/ff-log(19867): before parsing options
11-20 12:18:23.243: I/ff-log(19867): parse options
11-20 12:18:23.243: I/ff-log(19867): prepare app arguments !!! NOT defined(_WIN32) && !defined(__MINGW32CE__) !
11-20 12:18:23.243: I/ff-log(19867): after prepare app arguments
11-20 12:18:23.243: I/ff-log(19867): Unknown decoder '��f('
11-20 12:18:23.243: I/ff-log(19867): exit_program 1
11-20 12:18:23.243: I/ff-log(19867): exit_program 1
11-20 12:18:23.243: I/ff-log(19867): exit_program 2
11-20 12:18:23.253: A/libc(19867): @@@ ABORTING: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x1d3422d passed to dlfree
11-20 12:18:23.253: A/libc(19867): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 20393 (AsyncTask #2)
```

4th type:

```
11-20 12:20:07.214: I/ff-log(20660):   libavutil      51. 46.100 / 51. 46.100
11-20 12:20:07.214: I/ff-log(20660):   libavcodec     54. 14.101 / 54. 14.101
11-20 12:20:07.214: I/ff-log(20660):   libavformat    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
11-20 12:20:07.214: I/ff-log(20660):   libavfilter     2. 70.100 /  2. 70.100
11-20 12:20:07.214: I/ff-log(20660):   libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
11-20 12:20:07.214: I/ff-log(20660):   libswresample   0. 11.100 /  0. 11.100
11-20 12:20:07.214: I/ff-log(20660): before parsing options
11-20 12:20:07.214: I/ff-log(20660): before parsing options
11-20 12:20:07.214: I/ff-log(20660): parse options
11-20 12:20:07.214: I/ff-log(20660): prepare app arguments !!! NOT defined(_WIN32) && !defined(__MINGW32CE__) !
11-20 12:20:07.214: I/ff-log(20660): after prepare app arguments
11-20 12:20:07.214: I/ff-log(20660): Unknown decoder ''
11-20 12:20:07.214: I/ff-log(20660): exit_program 1
11-20 12:20:07.214: A/libc(20660): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x2d007165 (code=1), thread 21017 (AsyncTask #2)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the case since there is no code provided, but have you checked if you are reaching the stack limit ? (around 1MByte)

Comment: I haven't and to be honest I have no idea how to do it. This is my first project that is using NDK... 
I managed to compile the newest version of FFmpeg and SIGSEGV still occurs. I have now idea what is wrong with it. Maybe it's because I'm using FFmpeg.c instead of try to write my own C functions to handle video rotation etc ?!

Comment: I Don't have much idea on video effects, only some basic NDK knowledge. You should check if you are allocating too much to the stack - i.e. allocating a large array ("int[1024*1024]") of primitives without malloc.